# how to define epsilon interval in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Given the double number **p** and an epsilon **e**, how effectively we can check whether the given decimal number **x** lies in the interval **(p-e/2,p+e/2)** without using if and else condition.

Comment: Machine epsilon (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) is a concern in many languages. As Matlab is very high level and math orientated though, you can probably have any level of precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or

```
abs(x-p) < e/2
```

now some more characters to go over the 30 character minimum for posts

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
(x>=p-e/2) & (x<=p+e/2)
```